# Core Data Model set up

Tags: core-data

I have an expense tracking iOS Application using Core Data Model:

Scenario:

-> An abstract parent entity named "Money" with attributes "vendor", "date", "amount" and so on. The two sub-entities "Expense" and "Income" inherit from the parent entity "Money". Then there are other entities such as "Category" and "subCategory" with their attributes. Total as of now: 5 entities (Money, Expense, Income, Category and Subcategory) in my data model.

Question: What I want to achieve is to track expenses daily, per week, bi-weekly, monthly and yearly. I am thinking to make an entity say "Months" with 12 attributes ( Jan - Dec - > month names) but isn't that too much complicated?

Thoughts?

I have a Table-view and using NSFetchedResultsController to fill my table-view with the mix od expenses and Incomes.

Comment: Are your talking about filtering the tableView or do you want to calculate the average expenses (daily, weekly etc.)

Comment: I just want to set up my core data model properly which works as of now with all I above mentioned. But I do want to calculate expenses daily, per week, bi-weekly and then show it's graph using Core-Plot. So, I was wondering how would I sort it out as per date or months?

Comment: To make sure we're on the same page here: So you have collected some data and now want to process that data to receive something like this: expenses per day: $43; expenses per week: $301; ... Correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it. Like I saved some expense data as $43. I only have a "DATE" attribute in my "Money" (Parent entity). How will I manage to sort the expenses for a day, for a week, bi-weekly? Do I have to create another entity such as Months and have 12 month name attributes in there? I am confused here.

Comment: So basically you want to sum up all expenses in a given time period and divide them by the number of days, weeks, month etc. in the time period?

Comment: Or do you want to be able to list them like this: January expenses: $300, February expenses: $890 and so on?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Like In a UITableViewController, I can have section names as (Oct 1 - Oct 7, 2012 ) and table view would display the list of expenses made and its amount such as $ 350. Section names can be a week period, or bi-week (Oct 1 - Oct 14, 2012) depending on what we choose. So, how would I achieve that, given that I have only one time-period choosing attribute "DATE" in my entity. Is it possible by using just that attribute, I can achieve all this? You understood my question correctly though. It can be PER WEEK, PER 2 WEEKS, PER MONTH, PER 3 MONTHS (JAN - MAR) as well.

Comment: Did you get it, right? Do I have to add or modify my Core data model or what approach shall I follow in order to get it done?

Comment: No you don't have to modify your data model. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an `NSFetchRequest` with an `NSPredicate` that filters for the appropriate time period. Let's say you want to list all expenses between two dates your could implement a method that returns an `NSFetchRequest` that filters for this period:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)filteredFetchRequestForEntity:(NSString *)entityName startDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@", startDate, endDate];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    return fetchRequest;
}
```

You could then use this fetchRequest for example in an `NSFetchedResultsController`
similar to my answer in your other question: 
[CoreData and TableViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108252/core-data-and-table-views/13108396#13108396)

Then all you'd have to do is create the NSDate objects for start- and endDate for your desired time period and pass them to this method.

Comment: Oh ok! So, I don't have to really mess up with the core data model? Fetch requests with appropriate predicates would yield the required results?

Comment: Exactly, since you already have the dates when the expenses occurred, all you need to do is filter them appropriately. But if you want to display multiple time periods in different sections of the table view, it's get more complicated.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you know how shall I create the NSDate objects for start and end date ? Suppose, I am planning to calculate expenses for a week (start date Oct 1) end date (Oct 7) ? Actually, I do use a custom calendar in my app, which has start date and end date property, so I can just use that to create the object, right?

Comment: Correct. If your calendar delivers the selected dates as NSDate objects you're good to go. If it delivers strings you have to convert them to NSDate objects. Have a look at [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I appreciate you taking your precious time and helping me out here. Can you tell me how shall I contact you in near future because I know I will get stuck up somewhere or else in this application.

Comment: You're welcome. But I'm afraid I can't give you personal contact information (for one thing afaik there's no way to send PMs here and I won't post them publicly). Just ask you're questions here, there are many experienced developers here which can and will help you (in many cases much better than me ;)). As a general advice, you should put a little more afford in your questions. Be more precise and add related code, so people don't have to ask in the comments what exactly you want to achieve.